# How can the internal SSD be cloned onto an external 1 TB SSD (for swapping)?

Tags: disk-utility, partition, ssd, apfs

I want to clone my internal 500 GB SSD onto a new 1 TB SSD which is going to replace the internal 500 GB SSD in my MBP.

Currently the 500 GB SD is partitioned like the following:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.1 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.1 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Mac OS                  459.4 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 46.4 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                510.4 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

I tried to use the following command in Recovery Mode:

```
dd if=/dev/rdisk0 of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m
```

Will this work?
After dd finished, I was not able to mount disk2.
Do I have to change the dd command?

I was not yet able to swap the internal 500 GB SSD by the 1 TB one to check if it would boot. But I guess it won't :-(

disk2 looks after dd like this:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS                         1.0 TB     disk2s2
```

But Apple_APFS can't be mounted.
I am also wondering why it is recognized as 1.0 TB - I think after using dd it should be 500.1 GB (the size from 'Apple_APFS Container disk1').

I tried to find some information about cloning APFS volumes with EFI, Recovery, VM and Preboot stuff, but I could not find any useful information.

Maybe someone can help me here?
Thanks
Daniel

Comment: I've never tested it thorougly, but I see several weak spots in your approach: - the outer container size (1 TB) ≠ inner container size  (500.1 GB) (saved in block0 of disk2s2) - the corresponding UUIDs of the containers and volumes are all the same (UUID[disk0s2]=UUID[disk2s2]/container or UUID[disk1s2]=UUID[disk3s2]/Preboot etc.). Creating identical partition entries for disk0|>2s1 and disk0|>2s2 (leaving ~500GB free on the 1TB disk) and then cloning disk0s1 to disk2s1 and disk0s2 to disk2s2  (and later extending disk2s2) is more contructive. And removing disk0 could be essential then.

Comment: Interestingly your approach worked in my virtual environment after repairing the larger destination disk (here: `diskutil repairDisk disk1`) and removing disk0s1 & disk0s2 partitions with gpt (which doesn't affect the content of the partitions!). This could simply be related to how the hypervisor handles (virtual) disks though.

Comment: Today I will try Carbon Copy Cloner and add the VM partition with: „diskutil apfs addVolume disk1 APFS VM -role V“ If this will not work I will try dd and afterwards repairDisk.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently typing this from the system on the cloned 1 TB SSD, my solution was:

1. Clone internal 500 GB SSD with Carbon Copy Cloner 5 to the 1 TB SSD (using QNINE NVMe enclosure)
2. Swap 500 GB internal with 1 TB Sabrent Rocket NVMe
3. Directly boot into Recovery Mode
4. Added the missing VM container with the command: `diskutil apfs addVolume disk1 APFS VM -role V` I was not afraid of doing this because I found an Acronis script for cloning APFS volumes https://kb.acronis.com/content/60425 which executes the command pre restore. Interestingly the size of VM after the command was only some KB.
5. After booting Mojave the size of VM was 1.1 GB like before

Sadly we won't know if dd and afterwards `diskutil repairDisk disk1` would also have worked.

Thanks and I hope this post will help people with a MacBook Pro up to mid 2015 to upgrade the internal storage. (After mid 2015 Apple started to solder the storage onto the mainboard).

Answer (score 0):

Use Disk Utility or the `asr` command if you want native duplication.

Tools like carbon copy clones and super duper are even better at this task so you’ve got much more tailored tools than the disk destroyer, `dd`

- https://bombich.com/
- https://shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html

Every one of the above four tools won’t have any issues cloning from a smaller drive to a larger one. APFS also makes it easy to grow later as well.

It would also be valid to just wipe the external, install macOS and then clone just the macOS volume over the vanilla one and let Apple set up the external and bless it for boot.

Comment: Also, both products listed above blog regularly about how they worked through the various challenges to cloning. https://shirt-pocket.com/blog/ and https://bombich.com/blog plus they’ve been doing cloning software for decades each.

Comment: I am sorry but asr and Carbon Copy cloner did not work. CCC did not clone the VM volume. asr trew another error.